# set default month on select option if no request

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I have problem to set default selected value for current month if no request on the form.
Here is the code on blade file:

```
<select name="month">
@php
   $currMonth = date('m');
   $currMonthName = date('F');
@endphp
                                        
@foreach($months as $month => $monthName)
   <option @if($month == request()->get('month')) selected @endif value="{{ $month }}">{{ $monthName }}</option>
@endforeach

</select>
```

$months array from controller.

```
$months = [
   '01' => 'January',
   '02' => 'February',
   '03' => 'March',
   '04' => 'April',
   '05' => 'May',
   '06' => 'June',
   '07' => 'July',
   '08' => 'August',
   '09' => 'September',
   '10' => 'October',
   '11' => 'November',
   '12' => 'December'
 ];
```

The select option works fine on submit request, except for default value on page load. I want to set default value to current month. How to achieve this?

Comment: `$selectedMonth = request()->get('month') ?? $currMonth;` and compare with this variable.

Comment: The `->get()` method has 2 arguments, the key you're looking for and a default value if not present. Something like `request()->get('month', date('m'))` combined with your current code should work just fine for you :) (or `request()->get('month', $currMonth)` if you want to use a variable)

Comment: @Tim ok, thats even better :-)

Comment: @GertB. Haha yeah, they would both end up with the same outcome, definitely good to know the `??` option is there too 

Comment: thanks @TimLewis, problem solved :)

Comment: No problem :) Also, for conciseness, you can use a ternary for this: `<option value="{{ $month }}" {{ request()->get('month', date('m')) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $monthName }}</option>`. I've never been a fan of inline `@if ... @endif` like that, but small nitpick; they both work just fine.

Comment: Just for usability: `(request()->get('month') ?? old('month') ?? $currMonth) ? 'selected' : ''`

Comment: @Maksim personally I'm not a fan of multiple `??` and `? :` in one line. It seems less readable to me.

Comment: @GertB. and how you can implement `old()` without this in one line?

Comment: @Maksim Isn't the second parameter for `old()` the default value?